# deleting a file from an user account when only the guest account is accessible

Tags: permissions, files, .profile

I was trying stuff and my cousin (owning applestuff) sent me a bash_profile file.

I replaced it with my old profile file (the one you find in home, .profile) - I backed up the existing one as ".profile (old)"

I am now unable to sign in to my account, and can only log in using the guest account. How can I access my old account files to restore the backup I made?

Comment: I FIXED IT XD

trough system settings you can create a new account, then just open the new created account, gksu nautilus (just to be sure) navigate to /home/username/ delete the .profile file and rename ".profile (old)" to ".profile"

and problem fixed :)

sorry for the inconvenience :$

(i surely learned some today )

Comment: You might want to consider adding this as an answer.  click the checkbox that says "Answer your own question" at the bottom of the Ask Question page. Type in your answer, then submit both question and answer together.

Comment: yeah. i know. but since i havent got that much reputatuion i had to wait for 8hours to answer my own question :S
ill answer it right now :) thanks for the comment though :)

Answer (score 2):

I found out how! :D

when you enter guest mode, you can create another account (this is needed since guestmode cant access root priviliges (at least it prohibites me) ) 
i created a new administrator account ( i think it will work as well with a normal one, but just to be sure )

you can create this account just by accessing the system settings.

you login into you new administrator account, open the terminal and type "gksu nautilus"
(maybe it works with just nautilus, but im not sure if you can access other users files without gksu)

in nautilus, navigate to /home/username/

then delete the .profile file.
rename ".profile (old)" to ".profile"

and my problem was fixed :D

(this was just my thingiee.. but you can also open, edit etc the file or restore it from a backup.)

thanks for the views
hope my little mistake can help others with similar problems :)

at least i learned some :D

k thx bye ! :P